# How can I take values from a selection of columns in my Pandas dataframe to create a new column that contains a list of those values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Pandas where I would like to turn the values of a set of columns (more specifically, from column index 3 to the end) into a new single column that contains a list of those values in each row.

Right now, I have code that can print out a list of the values in the columns, but only for single row. How can I do this for the whole dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

orig_df = pd.read_csv('zipcode_price_dataset.csv')
df = orig_df.loc[(orig_df['State'] == "CA")]

row = df.head(1)

print(row[df.columns[3:].values].values[0])
```

I could iterate through the rows using a for loop, but is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```py
df['new'] = df[df.columns[3:]].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works but I get the warning: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". I intend to drop the columns that I got the values from, will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[: , 3:].agg(list, axis=1)
```